# what does a .php?id=&value=value means?

Tags: php, html, url, get

what does the id = &value = value means? what does & stands for?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about code you've written. Stack Overflow is not for speculating about what other sites are doing.

Comment: `$_GET['password']` will be `''` and `$_GET['submit']` will be `'submit'`.

Comment: http://www.aldeid.com/wiki/Hackthissite/Realistic/Level5

Comment: p.s. that's not PHP in the URL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Password and submit are URL parameters made available to the .php script via the global variable $_GET:

```
$_GET['password']
$_GET['submit']
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that $_GET['password'] (in this case) isn't set to anything.